# How To Read and Print Data from CSV file into HTML File as Text

Tags: javascript, python, html, csv

I've been trying to read data from .csv file and print the data as text/number into HTML file. Like the below example:

[image: Data from CSV file looks like this]

Now, I want to print in HTML like this:

Current age of ***Mr. abc*** is ***30*** Years. The bold & Italic text/numbers will be coming from the csv file and as soon as the csv file updated, the data in HTML will also update. Both the csv and HTML file will be in same local folder.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt, as an [edit] to your question, and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to use Python's built in CSV reader to correctly parse each row into a list of values. The can be done as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.html', 'w') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)    # skip the header
    
    # Write the HTML header
    f_output.write("<html>\n<body>\n")
    
    for row in csv_input:
        f_output.write(f"Current age of Mr. {row[0]} is {row[1]} Years.<br>\n")
        
    # Write the HTML footer
    f_output.write("</body>\n</html>\n")
```

For your sample CSV data, this would produce the following HTML output:

```html
<html>
<body>
Current age of Mr. abc is 20 Years.<br>
Current age of Mr. xyz is 30 Years.<br>
Current age of Mr. jkl is 40 Years.<br>
</body>
</html>
```

---

To create one HTML per row, you would need to rearrange things a bit and also decide on a naming scheme for the output files. This adds the name to each filename:

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)    # skip the header

    for row in csv_input:
        with open(f'output_{row[0]}.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_output:
            # Write the HTML header
            f_output.write("<html>\n<body>\n")

            f_output.write(f"Current age of Mr. {row[0]} is {row[1]} Years.<br>\n")
        
            # Write the HTML footer
            f_output.write("</body>\n</html>\n")
```

---

An alternative approach would be to parse each line yourself, this could be done as follows:

```
with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.html', 'w') as f_output:
    header = next(f_input)    # skip the header
    
    # Write the HTML header
    f_output.write("<html>\n<body>\n")
    
    for line in f_input:
        row = line.strip().split(',')
        f_output.write(f"Current age of Mr. {row[0]} is {row[1]} Years.<br>\n")
        
    # Write the HTML footer
    f_output.write("</body>\n</html>\n")
```

This though would not work if your single name column contained commas. e.g. `"John, Smith"` (which is valid in CSV files, the quotes are used to ignore the commas inside)

Comment: This works very well, thank you. Can it be modified to create a separate HTML output file for each CSV row, please?

Comment: You just need to move where the loop is. I have added an example

Answer (score 0):

The link to the CSV data is not valid, so it is difficult to say, but in general:

- read the CSV file and split the line into specific variables (see how to read a file, how to split the css, and assign into variables)
- the you can use the variables in HTML strings, you can use Jinja templates, but I believe that formatting the strings manually will do just fine.

So for example if the data file is `data.csv` and looks like this:

```
John:30
Emily:40
Carla:25
```

you can read it using the `with open` routine:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as datafile:
    data = datafile.readlines()
```

Now you have all the data in one list of lines, so you can iterate over the list and parse the data:

```
newdata = []
for line in data:
    newdata.append(line.rstrip().split(':'))
```

Now you should have all the couplets in the **newdata** list and you can use it as you wish. For instance to print out the HTML table, you could do:

```
print('<table>')
for couple in newdata:
    print(f"<tr><td>{couple[0]}</td><td>{couple[1]}</td></tr>")
print('</table>')
```

This will print out HTML code for the table. To be able to control the looks of some elements by CSS, you need to use a tag like `div` or `span` with some classes, like this:

```
for couple in newdata:
    print(f"The age of <div class="name">{couple[0]}</div> is <div class="age">{couple[1]}</div>.")
```

As already said, when the data is parsed, you can use whatever technique do produce the HTML - manual, Jinja templates, ... to save  out the HTML file.

Comment: This solution also works well, thank you! I had to add `encoding="utf-8"` because my CSV was multilingual and an encoding error showed up. Can you add some examples on outputting to one or more HTML files, please?

Answer (score -1):

Your link data file is not a valid link.
I'll still provide you a sample implementation that you can adapt to your case:

sameple.csv

```
Name, Age
ABC, 30
...
```

Have a separate script in same folder to create html based on your csv

```
csv_data=open('sample.csv','r').read().split('\n')
html_body = ''

for line in csv_data:
    line = line.split(',')
    html_body += f'<p>Mr. {line[0]} is {line[1]} Years</p>\n'

html_output = '<html><body>\n'+html_body+'</body></html>'
with open('html_out.html', 'w') as outfile:
outfile.write(html_output)
```